# Can't set OnItemClickListener on ListView when it has nested GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, listener

I have a `GridView` nested in `ListView` like this:

[image]

`ListView` contains events (rows) and `GridView` users attending (row items). Now I want to attach `OnItemClickListener` to my `ListView` but when I click on a row nothing happens. I tried to debug the issue and I figured out that Android is looking for a Listener set on `GridView` durring the row click. I want it to call Listener on `ListView` but I don't know how to force it to do so.

Comment: put your code.... where you are setting listeners.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is scrolable element as its takes most space of the row its parent(`ListView`) becomes untouchable.
 You need to make your `GridView` unscrollable. Its possible to do by extending `GridView` and ovveriding onMeasure method

```
public class NonScrollableGridView extends GridView {
    public NonScrollableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

The other option is to use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` insted of `ListView` and then not using `GridView`